# Como deixar o Objeto fixado na tela?

Tags: html5, css3, materialize

Estou tendo um problema de quando eu aumento ou diminuo o zoom do navegador, os meus "balões" eles seguem o respectivo comando, caso você aumente ele aumenta, caso você diminui ele diminui, porém eu gostaria de deixar eles com o posicionamento fixo na tela, para que eles não fiquem "sambando" pela tela quando utiliza um tablet ou mobile com tamanho de telas diferentes. Já tentei utilizar position:fixed porém não funciona.

**Utilizo:**

> Materialize

**Código HTML5:**

> ```
> <html>
>     <head>
>         <title>ShareTheHealth - Salve Vídas!</title>
>         <meta charset="UTF-8">
>         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
>         <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=index.html">
>         <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
>         <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/thankyou.css"/>
>         <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
>         <!-- AWESOME -->
>         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" media="screen,projection">
>         <!-- MATERIALIZE -->
>         <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
>         <link href="css/material-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
>     </head>
>     <body>
>         <main>
>             <!-- BALÃO 2 -->
>             <div class="row">
>                 <div class="col s12">
>                     <p class="balao2 white-text">Many thanks for your donation!</p>
>                 </div>
>             </div><!-- FIM BALÃO 2 -->
>             <!-- BALÃO 1 -->
>             <div class="row">
>                 <div class="col s12">
>                     <p class="balao white-text">Keep on helping us, we need you!
>                     </p>
>                 </div>
>             </div> <!-- FIM BALÃO 1 -->
>         </main>
>
>         <!-- MATERIALIZE -->
>         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
>         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
>     </body>
> </html>
> ```

**Código CSS3:**

> ```
> body {
>     background-image: url("../image/thanku.jpg");
>     background-size: 100%;
> }
>
> .balao {
>     margin-top: 13%;
>     margin-left: 17.7%;
>     float:left !important;
>     background-color:rgba(254,61,64,1);
>     border-right:10px solid transparent;
>     border-bottom:10px solid rgba(254,61,64,1);
>     background-clip: padding-box;
>     padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px;
> }
>
> .balao2 {   
>     margin-top: 15.2%;
>     margin-left: 10%;
>     float:left !important;
>     background-color:rgba(254,61,64,1);
>     border-right:10px solid transparent;
>     border-bottom:10px solid rgba(254,61,64,1);
>     background-clip: padding-box;
>     padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px;
> }
> ```

**Problema:**

[image: È PARA FICAR ASSIM, INDIFERENTE DO ZOOM]

[image: ERRO QUANDO DA ZOOM]

Comment: Colega só para ver se eu entendi mesmo... Quando diminui a tela os balões ficam desse tamanho **conforme a segunda imagem** e você deseja deixar do tamanho **conforme a primeira imagem** seria isso?

Comment: @Nathan é issto sim. Eu gostaria que eles ficassem no local fixo onde eu deixei no caso a primeira imagem, porém quando aumenta ou diminui o zoom eles ficam se movendo na tela igual a segunda imagem.

Comment: Colega você já tentou colocar z-index?

Answer (score -3):

** a regra position: fixed , que faz com que o elemento DIV permaneça fixo na tela. **

.balao2 {
margin-top: 15.2%;

```
margin-left: 10%;

float:left !important;

background-color:rgba(254,61,64,1);

border-right:10px solid transparent;

border-bottom:10px solid rgba(254,61,64,1);

background-clip: padding-box;

padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px;

position: fixed;
```

}